# Como enviar texto pelo template via url no Django?

Tags: python, django

Eu quero enviar texto para uma view através do template. Tenho dois tipos de clientes distintos que serão processados de forma diferente, para aproveitar código coloquei em uma view só e a parte específica tratei com um `if else`.

No template:

```
<a href="{% url 'cliente' 'prime' %}"> Cliente prime </a>
<a href="{% url 'cliente' 'free' %}"> Cliente </a>
```

No urls.py

```
....
path('cliente/<str:tipo>', Cliente, name='cliente'),
.....
```

Na view:

```
def Cliente(request, tipo):
    ...
    if tipo == "prime":
       ...
    else:
      ....
```

Contudo eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'cliente' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cliente\\/(?P<tipo>[^/]+)$']
```

Aparentemente não está passando o texto como parâmetro que inseri na url.

Nesse sentido, como posso passar um texto a partir do template via url?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dentro da views, verifique por usuario:
Identificar se é anonimo:

 if str(request.user) != "AnonymousUser":
     print("usuario não registrado, anonimo")
    ...teu código

if str(request.user) == "prime":
    ...teu código
      print("usuario prime")
    #Se houver algum compo que identifique se o usuario é prime
```

Answer (score -1):

tentei simular o mesmo erro que foram disponibilizados aqui mas não consegui.

Fiz como o descrito:

- numa página **index** sem muito código HTML coloquei os hiperlinks:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>TESTE</h1>
        <a href="{% url 'cliente' 'prime' %}"> Cliente prime </a>
        <a href="{% url 'cliente' 'free' %}"> Cliente </a>
    </div>

{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
</body>
</html>
```

- depois nas views, sem muita informação fiz quatro funções:

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def prime(request):
    return render(request, 'prime.html')


def free(request):
    return render(request, 'free.html')


def Cliente(request, tipo):
    if tipo == "prime":
        print(f'o request: {request} e o tipo: {tipo}')
        return redirect('prime')
    else:
        print(f'o request: {request} e o tipo: {tipo}')
        return redirect('free')
```

-e na urls.py encaminhei como de costume:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import index, prime, free, Cliente

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('prime/', prime, name='prime'),
    path('free/', free, name='free'),
    path('cliente/<str:tipo>', Cliente, name='cliente')
    ]
```

ao clicar nos **Hyperlinks** o texto gerado no terminal era:

*o request: <WSGIRequest: GET '/cliente/prime'> e o tipo: prime*

Em resumo: posso tentar ajudar, mas disponibilize mais informações do que está fazendo, ou verifique o que coloquei aqui e veja se esqueceu de alguma alguma coisa no teu código.